# Regarding $\mathscr{O}_X$ Modules and stalks

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Suppose that we have a topological space $X$ together with a sheaf of rings $\mathscr{O}_x$ such that for a sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ of abelian groups  we can define a $\mathscr{O}_x$ module.

1. Can the $\mathscr{O}_X$ module be interpreted as a natural transformation $\mathscr{O}_X \times \mathscr{F} \implies \mathscr{F}$?
2. In that case where's the product being taken? Are we considering both as sheaves : $X \rightarrow Set$?
3. When we take the stalk of $\mathscr{F}_p$ the equivalence relation defined depends on the nature of the maps? I mean even if we have a sheaf of abelian groups the nature of the stalk is just set theorical?

I was trying to prove that the stalk $\mathscr{F}_p$ was naturally a $\mathscr{O}_{X,p}$ module using the universal property.

Suppose we take the colimit of the product $\mathscr{O}_X \times \mathscr{F}$ that would be $\mathscr{O}_{X,p} \times \mathscr{F}_p$

Given $\mathscr{O}_X(U) \times \mathscr{F}(U) \rightarrow \mathscr{F}(U)\rightarrow \mathscr{F}_p$ by the universal property of the colimit  there should be a unique map :$\mathscr{O}_{X,p} \times \mathscr{F}_p \rightarrow \mathscr{F}_p$ with the desired commuting properties.

Maybe this is totally wrong but going in this direction i starting thinking about in which category this products are being taken. So I'd be very grateful if someone could clarify this concepts to me.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes. 3. In this case it does not matter.

Comment: Thanks! But then  I have the impression that we are implicitly using forgetful functors. If we've forgotten the algebraic structures in each $\mathscr{F}$ for example, how can we remember back?  

I mean we have a natural transformation $\mathscr{O}_X \times \mathscr{F} \implies \mathscr{F}$ but if we have constructed this in set how we can check that in each section it satisfies the usual axioms?

Comment: Obviously, you have to add those in as axioms.

Comment: Ok! One last thing. I'm sorry if all this is very stupid. 

In the last part of my question when I use the universal property of the colimit to give the $\mathscr{O}_{X,p}$ module structure over $\mathscr{F}_p$ I'm not showing that this mapping satisfies the desired axioms of a module. Those properties are inherit from the structure of the sections?

Or should I define the structure in a more "down to earth" way? I feel that with the unviersal property i'm only thinking about good commutativity conditions and nothing else.

Comment: These are induced from the structure on sections.